# What is a proper way to write h264 to mp4 container using mp4v2?

Tags: video, mp4, h.264, rtp

I've got a problem writing h264 frames got from RTP packet into MP4 file. The video playbacks with (e.g) command avplay/ffplay, but i'm getting these errors:

```
[h264 @ 0x7faebc006d40] no frame!0KB vq=   79KB sq=    0B f=0/9
```

and of course it looks like some frames are missed. 
 
The way I'm writing packets looks like:

1. Wait for packets with NAL type = 8 ( =SPS) and 7 (=PPS), for this
   time keep incoming packets in a list.
2. If NAL type is 28, it means the frame is divided - look for start
   bits and end bits and then create proper NAL unit and stick
   fragments together.
3. If we have found PPS and SPS tables, then create MP4 file:

   char * application_name = "isom";
   _mp4file = MP4CreateEx(name, 0,1,1,application_name,1);

   and then create VideoTrack:

   ```
    _video = MP4AddH264VideoTrack(_mp4file, _videoTimeScale, _videoTimeScale / _videoSampleDuration, _videoWidth, _videoHeight,
                                               _sps->getData()[1], //sps[1] AVCProfileIndication
                                               _sps->getData()[2], //sps[2] profile_compat
                                               _sps->getData()[3], //sps[3] AVCLevelIndication
   3); // 4 (minusOne) bytes length before each NAL unit
   ```

   and set some things up:

   ```
   MP4SetVideoProfileLevel(_mp4file, 0x7F);
   MP4AddH264SequenceParameterSet(_mp4file, _video, _sps->getData(), _sps->getSize());
   MP4AddH264PictureParameterSet(_mp4file, _video, _pps->getData(), _pps->getSize());
   ```
4. Flush waiting frames from list to file, with added frame size in Big Endian at the beginning:

   ```
   MP4WriteSample(_mp4file, _video, waitingFrame->getDataWithNalSize(), waitingFrame->getSize(), MP4_INVALID_DURATION, 0, 1);
   ```
5. Read RTP packets and write it in a loop to file:

   ```
   MP4WriteSample(_mp4file, _video, _videoFrame->getDataWithNalSize(), _videoFrame->getSize(), MP4_INVALID_DURATION, 0, 1);
   ```

RTP payloads consists of these types of NALs:
- PPS (8)
- SPS (7)
- Divided frames (28), after sticking I'm getting IDR (5) and non-IDR (1) video frames
- SEI (6)
- AUD (9)

Strange thing is that if I don't write PPS and SPS at the beginning of the file with MP4WriteSample function, I'm getting these errors (from avplay):

```
[h264 @ 0x7faebc006d40] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7faebc006d40] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7faebc008200] no frame!
```

But if I do, there's no erros.
So the real problem are SEI NALs. If I write them as they come in RTP stream (using MP4WriteSample), I'm getting "no frame" errors. But if I write only one SEI "frame" at the beginning of the file (using MP4WriteSample), I'm getting this kind of errors:

```
[h264 @ 0x7f1e48007d40] error while decoding MB 50 0, bytestream (-48)
[h264 @ 0x7f1e48007d40] concealing 1499 DC, 1499 AC, 1499 MV errors
[h264 @ 0x7f1e48008200] error while decoding MB 44 0, bytestream (-25)
[h264 @ 0x7f1e48008200] concealing 1500 DC, 1500 AC, 1500 MV errors
[h264 @ 0x7f1e48006d40] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 52 0
```

And then the picture is distorted (but then I have no "no frame" errors).

**So my question is what is proper way to write SEI (and maybe AUD?) NALs to mp4 container?**

In my project I have to use mp4v2 library or any other library with free to use license (this is reason why I can't use libav)

Comment: I am doing similar things. In my experience, the H264 stream is something like SPS, PPS, I-FRAME, S-FRAME, S-FRAME etc. frames. So if it is not started with SPS, it means that it is somewhere in S-FRAME most probably. Decoding of S-FRAME will be player dependent because it is not a complete frame (smaller size). Some player may say it's error and then stop playing. Some player will try best effort to play S-FRME (with some strange shadows here and there).

Answer (score 0):

The NALs you received from the RTP packets were starting with a start code 00 00 00 01, but the NALS mp4v2 need should start with a 4 bytes NAL lenth.